# How to set the value of multiple elements in an array in java "after" instantiating?

Tags: java

I'm making a game and want to throw some randomness into the generation, as such I need to set the value of all the elements in an array after making the array.

The best I can come up with so far is doing this 1 by 1 for each element, but I would like to do it all at once if possible.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
//"randomNo is set as a random number between 1 and 5 inclusive."
switch(randomNo){
    case 1: array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; break;
    case 2: array = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; break;
    case 3: array = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; break;
    case 4: array = {18, 19, 20, 21, 22}; break;
    case 5: array = {14, 15, 16, 17, 18}; break;
}
```

As such I can't just set the values at the start, but don't want to go 1 by 1 like so:

```
case 1: array[0] = 8; array[1] = 9;  array[2] = 10;  array[3] = 11;  array[4] = 12; break;
```

Comment: Use loops. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Comment: If you are using Java 12 you could use switch expressions to do it like `int[] array = switch(...) { ... } `. Otherwise just create new arrays like ` array = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};`.

Comment: Or you could just create the array in the case statement. array = new int[]{1,2,3};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the creation and initialization at the same time inside the switch, like this:

```
int[] array;
//"randomNo is set as a random number between 1 and 5 inclusive."
switch(randomNo){
    case 1: array = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; break;
    case 2: array = new int[]{8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; break;
    case 3: array = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; break;
    case 4: array = new int[]{18, 19, 20, 21, 22}; break;
    case 5: array = new int[]{14, 15, 16, 17, 18}; break;
    default: array = new int[5]; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hand-picking the random numbers (which isn't very random) let the Random library do the work for you:

```
  import java.util.Random;

  Random rand = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     array[i] = rand.nextInt();`
  }
```

Comment: Ah the issue with this is that the game is Battleships so the numbers can't be completely random, I feel like it'd be quicker to type out each element then do as you've said but with all the caveats of each number only being +/-1 from the last and so on.

Comment: @skyemelia So based on that generate the first number rand.nextInt(50) + 1; <between 1 and 50> then if the +/- 1 is random, you can generate a random number either 0 or 1, and either increment or decrement the next index accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and set each value to a random number. This example will do that for each value in array and assign a number between 1 and 50.

```
for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
    Random rand = new Random();
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
}
```